# Built Form with div block-content designed in two columns. Content within divs not filling full width of div

Tags: html, wordpress, forms

Wordpress 5.4.1

This was all working fine as shown in the image below but now it's not. I can think of two things that had happened since I last saw it working correctly; Wordpress updated, I moved to Cloudflare CDN. I don't know if a CDN would affect the way .css is read but I thought I'd mention it in case it gives an indication of what might have happened. Notice in the image below its two columns, evenly halved and each  is filling out the divs perfectly.

[image: 2 column form correct]

Now, this is how it's displaying:

[image: incorrect 2 column display]

When I inspect the page, you can see the div's true width and the margin dividing the 2 columns, but for some reason the content it filling anymore (see the image before). Also, when I mess around with the div widths, the div width does increase, but the content doesn't get any wider.

[image]

Here is the form HTML:

```
<h3 class="form_title" style="text-decoration: underline;">Contact Details</h3> 
<div class="one-half">
<label> First Name *
[text* your-first-name] </label>
</div>
<div class="one-half last">
<label> Last Name *
[text* your-second-name] </label>
</div>

<div class="one-half">
<label> Your Email *
[email* your-email] </label>
</div>

<div class="one-half last">
<label> Contact Number *
[tel* your-tel] </label>
</div>

<h3 class="form_title" style="text-decoration: underline;">Company Details</h3> 

<div class="one-half">
<label> Business Name
[text your-business-name placeholder "Organisation or Business"] </label>
</div>

<div class="one-half last">
<label> Your position
[text your-position placeholder "e.g. Owner, Manager, Head of IT, etc"] </label>
</div>

<div style="text-align:left;width:48%;margin-right:4%;margin-bottom:20px;overflow:hidden;">
<label> Number of Staff
[select NumberofStaff placeholder "== select ==" "Just me!" "1-3" "3-5" "5-10" "10-20" "20- 
50" "50-100" "100+"]</label>
</div>

<div class="full-spread">
<label> Business Description
[textarea business-description placeholder "Please give a brief description of your 
business. This will help us with any functionality you may require on your site."]</label>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
/* Contact Form 7 */

span.wpcf7-list-item { display: block; }

.one-half,
.one-third {
    position: relative;
    margin-right: 4%;
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    overflow:hidden;

}


.one-half { width: 48%; }
.one-third { width: 30.66%; }

.last {
    margin-right: 0 !important;
    clear: right;
}

.elementor-866 .elementor-element.elementor-element-5ab526a .eael-contact-form-7 .wpcf7- 
form-control.wpcf7-textarea {
    margin-bottom:-1%;
    padding-top:;
}
```

Comment: Can you give link example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add this code to css will resolve your problem:

```
.elementor-866 .elementor-element.elementor-element-5ab526a .eael-contact-form-7 .wpcf7-form label{
width:100%!important;
}
```